# Calling a returned function gives "not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, function, fetch-api, wordle-game

I have this fake wordle game
I think that the problem is with fetching the api and returning the functions for validation. I get an error that "`getData(...).isCorrect` is not a function" whenever I press submit and when I try without the parenthesis in index.html, the game won't display anything. Is there another way to do this, or is this just a simple bug in my code?

```js
async function getData() {
  var response = await fetch("https://all-wordle-words.kobyk1.repl.co/script.js");
  var data = await response.json();

  const wordsArray = data;
  const words = new Set(wordsArray);
  const chosen = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)];

  function check(word) {
    let result = Array(5).fill("gray");
    let chosenChars = [...chosen];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (word[i] === chosenChars[i]) {
        result[i] = "green";
        chosenChars[i] = "G";
      } else {
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
          if (word[i] === chosenChars[j]) {
            result[i] = "yellow";
            chosenChars[j] = "Y";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  function isCorrect() {
    let word = document.getElementById("guess").value.toLowerCase();

    if (words.has(word)) {
      result = check(word);
      let element = document.getElementById("guesses");
      element.innerHTML += colorResult(word, result);
      if (chosen === word) {
        alert("You found the word!");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, that word is not in our dictionary!");
    }
  }

  function colorResult(word, result) {
    word = word.toUpperCase();
    let columns = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      columns += `<td style="background-color: ${result[i]};">${word[i]}</td>`;
    }
    return "<tr>" + columns + "</tr>";
  }

  return {
    check,
    isCorrect,
    colorResult
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>KORDLE</h1>
<table id="guesses">
  <tr></tr>
</table>

<br>

<input type="text" id="guess">
<button onclick="getData().isCorrect()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and wrote a title that described the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value), your function returns a promise not an object.

So just try to replace

```
<button onclick="getData().isCorrect()">Submit</button>
```

with

```
<button onclick="getData().then(obj => obj.isCorrect())">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Also, I now have the problem where the world changes every time I hit submit, how would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the async function with a .then

I would use an eventListener and change the name of the function since it does way more than just getting data

```
init().then((myInit) => {
  document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", () => myInit.isCorrect());
});
```

```js
async function init() {
  var response = await fetch("https://all-wordle-words.kobyk1.repl.co/script.js");
  var data = await response.json();

  const wordsArray = data;
  const words = new Set(wordsArray);
  const chosen = wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)];
  console.log(chosen)
  function check(word) {
    let result = Array(5).fill("gray");
    let chosenChars = [...chosen];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (word[i] === chosenChars[i]) {
        result[i] = "green";
        chosenChars[i] = "G";
      } else {
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
          if (word[i] === chosenChars[j]) {
            result[i] = "yellow";
            chosenChars[j] = "Y";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  function isCorrect() { 
    let word = document.getElementById("guess").value.toLowerCase();

    if (words.has(word)) {
      result = check(word);
      let element = document.getElementById("guesses");
      element.innerHTML += colorResult(word, result);
      if (chosen === word) {
        alert("You found the word!");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, that word is not in our dictionary!");
    }
  }

  function colorResult(word, result) {
    word = word.toUpperCase();
    let columns = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      columns += `<td style="background-color: ${result[i]};">${word[i]}</td>`;
    }
    return "<tr>" + columns + "</tr>";
  }

  return {
    check,
    isCorrect,
    colorResult
  }
}

init().then((myInit) => {
  document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", () => myInit.isCorrect());
});
```

```html
<h1>KORDLE</h1>
<table id="guesses">
  <tr></tr>
</table>

<br>

<input type="text" id="guess">
<button id="sub">Submit</button>
```